# How to show that someone beleive someone don't beleive $\phi$ with Kripke models?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

I want to model a logic of beliefs with two agents where :

$$M,w^*⊨\phi\wedge Ba\phi\wedge Bb\neg\phi\wedge BaBb\neg\phi$$

*I think I'm using Kripke semantics.*

I think that *i.e.* it describe a world where it exists $\phi$, $a$ beleives it, $b$ don't believe it and $a$ believes $b$ don't believe it.

I thought about :

[image]

Even if I wasn't sure about the arrow of $a$ on $\phi$ and $b$ on $\neg\phi$.
Yet it didn't displayed the fact that $a$ believes that $b$ don't believe $\Phi$.

The answer the teacher gave was :

[image]

I understand that the $w^*$ shows that the actual world is on the left side but on the right side I don't understand this part as far as, to my mind, it shows that b believes $\neg\phi$ as well which is wrong in logic of belief.